# Visual Studio: EMACS-like white space removal

Tags: visual-studio-2013

my coworker and i wonder if there is a way to teach visual studio to do something like emacs is able to: place the cursor *anywhere* in a series of whitespace in code, press ALT-SPACE shortcut (or the defined one) and boom only one space character left.

does anyone know if a *simple* solution exists to do this? maybee even without installing extensions or other stuff?

i already tried shortcuts like STRG-DEL but it depends on the cursor position what is deleted and that is not exactly what we are searching for.

thanks in advance, cheers! jens

ps: caps lock is reverse broken, sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just found out... VS **HAS** a feature to do this... unfortunately, in 2012 it is not working, in 2015 is is... weirdo... default is

```
STRG + E, ^
```

you also find it in EDIT >> ADVANCED menu.

best regards,
jens

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

Ctrl + H
Find what:
[\u0020]+\r?\n
Replace with:
\r\n
\s instead of [\u0020] delete empty line feeds, probably because it matches line feeds

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but using search/replace is not really the same as an instant change after pressing a kombination of keys, like, pressing STRG-C copies the currently selected text without opening a dialogue to select the text which shall be copied.

Answer (score 0):

**Ctrl+E, Ctrl+** is what works on my keyboard, not sure what 'strg' is, maybe a different term for 'control"??  You can also achieve this with **Ctrl+K, Ctrl+** (a keyboard "chord"), as long as you have your cursor within the spaces you want to reduce.

In some cases in Visual Studio 2015, these spaces will be eliminated when you press the chord for file reformatting in general: **Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D**.  However, it seems to depend on factors I'm not certain of...  something I'll be posting about in StackOverflow later.